# Overriding generic abstract method's return type without type safety warnings

Tags: java, generics, abstract

In some `SuperClass` I have an abstract generic method:

```
protected abstract <T extends Foo> T getFoo();
```

In my `SubClass` I try to override it with:

```
@Override
protected SubFoo getFoo() {             
    return new SubFoo();
}
```

where `public class SubFoo extends Foo`

in my subclass's `getFoo` I get the following error.

"Type safety: The return type SubFoo for getFoo() from the type SubClass needs unchecked conversion to conform to T from the type SuperClass"

My questions are:

1) Is there any scenario where this is not safe ?

2) If not, shouldn't the compiler be able to figure that out ? what is preventing the compiler from figuring out that SubFoo is a subclass of Foo at compile time ?

3) Is there a way to achieve something like this, but warning free ?

Comment: That is inherently unsafe.  What if I call your method with a different type parameter?

Comment: @Oren you are violating Liskov Substitution Principle  by doing this ... Your supertype can not be replaced by your subtype

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is unsafe and illegal.  The `SuperClass` declaration you've written allows the *caller* -- not the `SuperClass` subclass -- to choose which subtype of `Foo` it wants, so your implementation in `SubClass` doesn't implement it properly.

Instead, you must have `T` as a generic parameter for `SuperClass` itself, not just the method: `SuperClass<T extends Foo>`, and then `SubClass extends SuperClass<SubFoo>`.

Comment: don't know about illegal (it compiles and no one came around to arrest me yet :) ) but I get now how this is unsafe. thank you for your quick response, your answer resolved my issue.